# JavaScript split with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list, that i am getting from a http get request, on this list every item has a button to exclude itself, and as excluded, it dynamically bind to the view taking off that element, because i am splitting the same object that is being render in the view. 
The problem is, i send to exclude the fist item, and it excludes the second, for example, and i really don't know why. "Index" for the split function is being send by vuejs, and is correct. Does anyone have any clue about what is going on?

some parts of the code below:

```
<tr v-for="(teamLeader, index) in data">
       <td>{{index}}</td>

        <span class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" disabled>|</span> 
         <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" @click="confirmDelete(index,teamLeader.id)">Delete</a>
</tr>
```

and the delete method:

```
deleteFunction: function(index,supportAreaId){
                API.delete('users/').then(response =>{
                    this.toast("success");
                    this.data.splice(index,1);
                })
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrnogueira/0twuem2s/

Comment: confirmDelete ?

Comment: it`s a function that calls a modal, and then, if the person says that it wants to exclude it calls delete function

Comment: but i have already tried to change to deleteFunction and the result is the same

Comment: This seems correct. Are you retrieving the users again after you delete one? It could be an async thing.

Comment: Well, posted code won't have described issue, it's correct (providing that deleteFunction is called with correct index). Thus, this question is not answerable without more details.

Comment: @BillCriswell no, i`m not, i will try this, thanks!

Comment: @dfsq i am doing a fiddle, just a sec

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrnogueira/0twuem2s/

Comment: start deleting Lenovo, for exemple, you will see that it is not deleted

Comment: you are using vue 1x? there is no such issue with v2

Comment: is v2, i dont really know what is going on whith this :/ 
Can you send me the github issue of 1x? just to have a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0twuem2s/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0twuem2s/6/ works too

Comment: yeah, is this fiddle id working, don't know why, in the code i put this fiddle and stop working haha. But thank so much for the help!

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira in your jsfiddle you include vue `1.x` and don't define `index` (if you console.log it inside a function, you'll see it's undefined). Swap vue to 2.x and define the `index` variable `v-for="(item, index) in ..."`